# How to plot values of my columns being above a certain treshold?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, seaborn

I've been stuck with this problem for a while. I have a dataset which looks more or less like this:

```
Students     Subject       Mark
1            M F           7 4 3 7
2            I             5 6 
3            M F I S       2 3 0 
4            M             2 2 
5            F M I         5 1
6            I M F         6 2 3
7            I M           7
```

Now, I want to create a barplot using pandas and seaborn showing how many students:

- Have 3 ore more letters in the column "Subject"
- Have at least one 3 in the colum "Marks"
- Have both things

I tried with:

```
n_subject = dataset['Subject'].str.count('\w+')
dataset['NumberSubjects']= n_subject
n_over = dataset[dataset.n_subject >= 3.0]
```

But it does not work and I'm stuck. I'm sure it is a very basic problem but I don't know what to do.

Comment: `dataset[dataset.n_subject >= 3.0]` doesn't make sense, because you have assigned that Series in the line above with the name 'NumberSubjects', so the filter should be: `dataset[dataset['NumberSubjects'] >= 3]`

Comment: @ALollz you're right! But if I do `n_over = dataset[dataset['NumberSubjects'] >= 3]` and I print it, it just gives me back my dataset

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what should be the barplot representing (summary of Mark?) But here is what you need for filtering purposes. Also, string count counts empty spaces too, but there are multiple ways of handling this. I am just giving you an idea what / how to do it.

```
>>> m1 = df.Subject.apply(lambda x: len(x.split()) >= 3)
>>> m2 = df.Mark.str.contains('3')
>>> m3 = m1|m2

>>> df[m1]
   Students  Subject    Mark
2         3  M F I S  2 3 0
4         5    F M I     5 1
5         6    I M F   6 2 3
    
>>> df[m2]

   Students  Subject     Mark
0         1      M F  7 4 3 7
2         3  M F I S   2 3 0
5         6    I M F    6 2 3

>>> df[m3]

   Students  Subject     Mark
0         1      M F  7 4 3 7
2         3  M F I S   2 3 0
4         5    F M I      5 1
5         6    I M F    6 2 3
```

Comment: True, that's what I had put in the `disclaimer` part of the answer :-) Fixed it now though

Comment: Thank you! My barplot shoudl show four bars: one when m1 is true, one when m2 is respected, a third one when m3 is respected and a last one if none of the conditions apply. However, I'm really not sure what to do form here.

Answer (score 0):

3 or more subjects:

```
df["Subject"].str.count("\w+") >= 3
```

Has one or more marks of 3:

```
df["Mark"].str.count("3") >= 1
```

Both:

```
(df["Subject"].str.count("\w+") >= 3) & (df["Mark"].str.count("3") >= 1)
```

Boolean representation:

```
   Students  Subject     Mark    one    two  three
0         1      M F  7 4 3 7  False   True  False
1         2        I      5 6  False  False  False
2         3  M F I S    2 3 0   True   True   True
3         4        M      2 2  False  False  False
4         5    F M I      5 1   True  False  False
5         6    I M F    6 2 3   True   True   True
6         7      I M        7  False  False  False
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I'm still not sure about how to go form here to plotting it. When I plot a graph I'm usually doing something like: `sns.countplot(x= "---", data =dataset)`. But here I have no idea how to graph all three "columns"